# Hadoop - failed to specify server's Kerberos principal name

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, kerberos

**Error - Failed to specify server's Kerberos principal name**

I am trying to setup a Hadoop cluster using Kerberos. I managed to get the cluster working with Spark and Yarn before starting the Kerberos configuration. Currently my master and three nodes are running but i'm getting an error in the yarn logs.

Error:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException : Failed to specify server's Kerberos principal name
```

core-site.xml

```
<configuration>

    <property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://hadoopmaster:9000</value>
    </property>

    <!--Kerberos configuration-->

    <property>
        <name>hadoop.security.authentication</name>
        <value>kerberos</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hadoop.security.authorization</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hadoop.security.auth_to_local</name>
      <value>
        RULE:[2:$1@$0](hdfs/.*@.*EXAMPLEREALM.COM)s/.*/hdfs/
        RULE:[2:$1@$0](HTTP/.*@.*EXAMPLEREALM.COM)s/.*/hdfs/
        RULE:[2:$1@$0](yarn/.*@.*EXAMPLEREALM.COM)s/.*/yarn/
        DEFAULT
      </value>
    </property>

</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
        <value>/home/hadoop/data/namenode</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
        <value>/home/hadoop/data/datanode</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication<name>
        <value>2</value>
    </property>

    <!-- General HDFS security config -->
    <property>
      <name>dfs.block.access.token.enable</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <!-- NameNode security config -->
    <property>
      <name>dfs.namenode.keytab.file</name>
      <value>/etc/security/keytabs/hdfs.service.keytab</value> <!-- path to the HDFS keytab -->
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>dfs.namenode.kerberos.principal</name>
      <value>hdfs/hadoopslave1.examplerealm.com@EXAMPLEREALM.COM</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>dfs.namenode.kerberos.internal.spnego.principal</name>
      <value>HTTP/hadoopslave1.examplerealm.com@EXAMPLEREALM.COM</value>
    </property>

    <!-- Secondary NameNode security config -->
    <property>
      <name>dfs.secondary.namenode.keytab.file</name>
      <value>/etc/security/keytabs/hdfs.service.keytab</value> <!-- path to the HDFS keytab -->
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>dfs.secondary.namenode.kerberos.principal</name>
      <value>hdfs/hadoopslave1.examplerealm.com@EXAMPLEREALM.COM</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>dfs.secondary.namenode.kerberos.internal.spnego.principal</name>
      <value>HTTP/hadoopslave1.examplerealm.com@EXAMPLEREALM.COM</value>
    </property>

    <!-- DataNode security config -->
    <property>
      <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir.perm</name>
      <value>700</value> 
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>dfs.datanode.address</name>
      <value>0.0.0.0:1004</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>dfs.datanode.http.address</name>
      <value>0.0.0.0:1006</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>dfs.datanode.keytab.file</name>
      <value>/etc/security/keytabs/hdfs.service.keytab</value> <!-- path to the HDFS keytab -->
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>dfs.datanode.kerberos.principal</name>
      <value>hdfs/hadoopslave1.examplerealm.com@EXAMPLEREALM.COM</value>
    </property>

    <!-- Web Authentication config -->
    <property>
      <name>dfs.web.authentication.kerberos.principal</name>
      <value>HTTP/hadoopslave1.examplerealm.com@EXAMPLEREALM.COM</value>
     </property>

 </configuration>
```

yarn-site.xml

```
<configuration>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.acl.enable</name>
        <value>0</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
        <value>hadoopmaster</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce_shuffle.class</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.principal</name>
      <value>yarn/hadoopslave1.examplerealm.com@EXAMPLEREALM.COM</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.keytab</name>
      <value>/etc/security/keytabs/yarn.service.keytab</value>
    </property>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed `krb5-libs` and `krb5-workstation` on all nodes?

on Centos:

```
yum install krb5-server  krb5-libs
yum install  krb5-libs krb5-workstation
```

In that case, trying this might help you:

```
systemctl enable krb5kdc 
systemctl start krb5kdc
systemctl enable kadmin 
systemctl start kadmin
```

*Also check:
 https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/176262/failed-to-specify-servers-kerberos-principal-name.html*